# Unable to vertically center a Row composable children using android jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am an android developper and I am  beginning with jetpack compose. I was following
a tutorial and i've encountered a problem . I cannot center vertically a row child using   verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically . There is impact on the preview screen . Here is the code :

```
   @Composable
fun HorizontalScreen(){

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Text(text = "Text 1")
        Text(text = "Text 2")
        Text(text = "Text 3")
        Text(text = "Text 4")

    }

}


@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun HorizontalScreenPreview(){
    HorizontalScreen()
}
```

Comment: You can try to wrap your Row inside a Column and set the vertical alignment on the Column

Comment: @BernardoAlmeida thanks ! But could you explain me why this code don't work ?

Comment: By default Row height it wrapped to content if you want to check whether it works just assign ```Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(50.dp)``` height to it and it will show a preview working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, when you do

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
```

the Column will

- fill the maximum width of the screen
- adjust its height to wrap the content.

Because the Column already perfectly wraps its children, there is no visible difference when you use `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically`. So change your code to

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight()
```

to see the expected `verticalAlignment` behaviour.

[image]